# Trigger JS after facet search selection

Tags: bigcommerce

Using BigCommerce Enterprise, any ideas on how I can trigger a JS function to run *after* the facet search either loads, or when a selection is made by a user?

Specifically, i'm trying to update elements within the js-facet-wrapper class. My issue is that my functions can't see or use these objects when I use document ready...

Appreciate any input.

Comment: if you're coming to this question in 2023, facetwp now has the js [`facetwp-refresh`](https://facetwp.com/help-center/developers/javascript-reference/facetwp-refresh/) (before any AJAX fires) and [`facetwp-loaded`](https://facetwp.com/help-center/developers/javascript-reference/facetwp-loaded/) (after the request comes back with data) events

Answer (score 4):

Because the filters are loaded via ajax, you need to bind your events to a parent which is present on page load, then grab the child element (which is loaded via ajax) from there. See example below.

```
$('.Left').on('click', '.facet-option.js-facet-option', function(){
    adjustClasses();
});
```

I've done something similar when trying to adjust the default functionality of the mobile faceted search dropdown to make the filters slide out from off the screen, then closing the menu when any filter is selected, or the overlay is clicked.

I am listening for clicks on any of the facets, etc. and adjusting the classes accordingly.

```
$(".close-filter-menu").on("click", function(){
    $('.page').removeClass("filters");
    $('.filter-overlay').removeClass("filters-open");
    $(".Left.fleft.js-faceted-search-column").removeClass("mobile-in-view open");
})

$('.js-faceted-search-action.btn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var slideoutMenu = $('.Left.fleft.js-faceted-search-column');
    var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.Left.fleft.js-faceted-search-column').width();
    var overlay = $(".filter-overlay");

    // toggle open class
    slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

    // slide menu
    if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
        slideoutMenu.animate({
            right: "0px"
        });
        $('html,body').scrollTop(0); 
        $('.page').addClass("filters");
        overlay.addClass("filters-open");
    } else {
        slideoutMenu.animate({
            left: -slideoutMenuWidth
        }, 250);    

    }
});

function adjustClasses(){
    var width = $( window ).width();
    if( width <= 768 ){
        $(".page").removeClass("filters");
        $(".filter-overlay").removeClass("filters-open");            
        $(".Left.fleft.js-faceted-search-column").removeClass("open");
        $(".Left.fleft.js-faceted-search-column").removeClass("mobile-in-view");
    }
}

$("html").on("click", "#ModalContainer .facet-option.js-facet-option", function(){
    adjustClasses();
});
$('.Left').on('click', '.facet-option.js-facet-option', function(){
    adjustClasses();
});
$('.Left').on('click', 'p.narrow-results-header', function(){
    adjustClasses();
});
$('.Left').on('click', '.btn.js-btn-facet-range-update', function(){
    adjustClasses();
});
$('.ToggleFilters').on('click', function(){
    adjustClasses();
});
$('.Left').on('click', '.filter-overlay.filters-open').on('click', function(){
    adjustClasses();
});
$('.Left').on('click', '.btn.btn-facet-more-options.more').on('click', function(){
    adjustClasses();
});
```

To run functions once the filters have originally, you can use ajaxStop();

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  $('.js-faceted-search-action.btn').addClass("just-loaded");
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that looks like it will work, though it appears all your triggers are based on a click, what about initial load, for instance when the user first loads the page and a selection hasnt been made yet.

Comment: See my edit. I think that is what your looking for. If not, please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The faceted search is loaded via its own Xhr/Ajax request, which is made after the document has become 'ready'. Once the request is made, it will take several seconds to receive the response and inject it into the DOM. This is why you cannot access the elements upon document ready, because they have not been loaded yet.

The ideal solution would be to locate the function responsible for performing the Xhr request that loads the faceted search, and inserting a call to your own function in its callback (the callback which receives the faceted search response). Unfortunately I do not know where in the template this function is located, although I would be interested in knowing.

In the meantime, a less than ideal solution would be to simply wait for all Ajax requests on the page to finish, and then call your function, since you can be sure then that the faceted search has been loaded: 
**[ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)**

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  //All Ajax requests finished, call your function here...
  //You can also safely bind to and access the faceted search elements now. 
});
```